# Rust: x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3

Tags: gcc, rust, mingw, glfw

I'm trying to use GLFW with rust on windows and I'm getting this error upon running the program:

```
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" (then a ton of other stuff that leaks my files)
  = note: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3
          collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All I am doing in the program is importing the package.

I have been trying to solve this for a while, and it doesn't help that I'm very new to rust. I guess this is what I get with trying to use rust on windows.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have GLFW 3.x installed on your system? Its a prerequisite for using this crate, the [readme](https://crates.io/crates/glfw) has links to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @kmdreko Thank you for your response! I just attempted to install it but am still getting the same error. I am not entirely sure how exactly to install it and how to tell it where the directory is. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `-L<path>` linker flag where `<path>` points to the folder containing `libglfw3.a` (or `libglfw3.dll.a` in case of shared library).